# Start app by shaking the phone based on broadcastreceiver listening for a corresponding intent if possible?

Tags: android

Are there any system/default intents that could be caught by a broadcastreceiver or may be a service that can run in a background and open my app when i shake the phone!

Can the concepts of accelerometer and broadcast receivers be combined to achieve the above or there is something fundamentally wrong with this approach?

Comment: I see, you're thinking of implementing some kind of man-down functionality. Sounds interesting. In that case i'm deleting my NO-GO answer :) - take a look at http://actionxl.com/CRADAR.html

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I am trying to do. Super duper thanks!